# storing data in numpy array without overwriting previous data

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

i am running a for loop to store the data in a numpy array. the problem is that after every iteration previous data is overwritten by latest one . i want to be able to store all data bu using some "extend" function as used for simple arrays. i tried append but it's not storing all the values of all arrays.

**code**

```
data1=np.empty((3,3),dtype=np.int8)
top_model_weights_path = '/home/ethnicity.071217.23-0.28.hdf5'
df = pd.read_csv('/home/instaurls.csv')
for row in df.itertuples():
    data = io.imread(row[1])
    data1=np.append(data1,data)
print(data1)
```

**expected output**

```
[[[ 34  34  34]
  [ 35  35  35]
  [ 40  40  40]
  ..., 
  [  8   8   8]
  [ 12  12  12]
  [ 12  12  12]]

 [[ 39  39  39]
  [ 30  30  30]
  [ 25  25  25]
  ..., 
  [ 11  11  11]
  [  1   1   1]
  [  5   5   5]]

 [[ 54  54  54]
  [ 44  44  44]
  [ 34  34  34]
  ..., 
  [ 32  32  32]
  [  9   9   9]
  [  0   0   0]]

 ..., 
 [[212 212 210]
  [167 167 165]
  [118 118 116]
  ..., 
  [185 186 181]
  [176 177 172]
  [170 171 166]]

 [[220 220 218]
  [165 165 163]
  [116 116 114]
  ..., 
  [158 159 154]
  [156 157 152]
  [170 171 166]]

 [[220 220 218]
  [154 154 152]
  [106 106 104]
  ..., 
  [144 145 140]
  [136 137 132]
  [158 159 154]]]
```

Comment: why you are using `numpy.append()` with dataframe? Use `data1.append(data)` instead. For more details [pandas append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar without it, i get the error 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'. i am using the numpy array because image being read is converted into numpy array

Comment: ok so you want `data1` as `numpy array` or dataframe?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar numpy

Comment: provide expected output from above code. From `np.append` you can get 1D array only and I'm assuming you want 2D array as output.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar i have added the output. it's just by combining two arrays ad in the similar way i want multiple arrays to be combined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164969/discussion-between-rehan-and-akshay-nevrekar).

Comment: Don't use `np.append` iteratively.  it is slow and seldom used correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
top_model_weights_path = '/home/ethnicity.071217.23-0.28.hdf5'
df    = pd.read_csv('/home/instaurls.csv')
data1 = np.array([io.imread(row[1]) for row in df.itertuples()])
```

If your dataset is not too big, there is no problem with using a standard list first and then convert to numpy array, I guess.

If you're not familiar with implicit lists:

```
data1 = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    data1.append(io.imread(row[1]))
data1 = np.array(data1)
```

Comment: exactly what i needed. although in the long run my dataset is going to get large as i am building up this model for big data but this should work for now. thanks a ton!